# video as background not loading

Tags: html, css, video, background

If I use the src from the web with src="http........" it works but it doesn't work if src  is uploaded from my computer?

I tried this code:

```
 <video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="../documents/Sent files/VID-20190106-WA0001.mp4" type="video/mp4"/> 
 </video>
```

and I also tried this code"

```
 <video autoplay loop playsinline muted src="../../documents/Sent files/VID-20190106-WA0001.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

but this works:

```
<video src="https://css-tricks-post-videos.s3.us-east- 
 1.amazonaws.com/708209935.mp4" autoplay loop playsinline muted></video>
```

Comment: will it work if you use it as a normal video and not as a background?

Comment: **(1)** Drag the video into an new (empty) browser tab. It should play, but also showing the correct video path. Copy the path from browser and test as path in your code.

Answer (score 2):

if html file and video file are in same directory you must set src without "../"

[image]

Comment: this image show position of files and purpose of it not code

Comment: I added the video to the same folder , it works now, ty but before they were not in the same folder, thats why I accessed the file with ../

Comment: In that case, you should instead use `./` **with only one dot**

Comment: ../ means parent folder and ./ means same folder. in some environments it possible you can't access parent folder